# How do i get the modhash and cookie from logging into reddit with the api?

Tags: objective-c, json, reddit

```
NSString *username = @"username";
NSString *password = @"password";
NSURL *loginurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.reddit.com/api/login/%@",username]];
NSMutableURLRequest *loginrequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:loginurl];
[loginrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *loginRequestBody = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"api_type=json&user=%@&passwd=%@",username,password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[loginrequest setHTTPBody:loginRequestBody];
NSURLResponse *loginResponse = NULL;
NSError *loginRequestError = NULL;
NSData *loginResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:loginrequest returningResponse:&loginResponse error:&loginRequestError];
NSString *loginResponseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:loginResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",loginResponseString);
```

the NSLog prints this: (with some letters replaced)

> {"json": {"errors": [], "data": {"modhash":
>   "j5hq16ukw2f17a9c153xxxxxxxxxa72ad989c96c904d49a97e", "cookie":
>   "13986184,2012-07-14T12:41:05,349f968b3089af75978xxxxxxxxxxxx761397ba0"}}}

How do i access the modhash and the cookie? I tried

```
[loginResponseData valueForKey:@"json"];
```

but it says that the class is not key value coding-compliant for the key json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this after me, you can check out H2CO3's solution, but I found that the easiest solution was using NSJSONSerialization to do it in a supported fashion.

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [loginResponseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *loginResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
NSString *modhash = [[[loginResults valueForKey:@"json"] valueForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"modhash"];
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

loginResponseString is an NSString -- it doesn't know if it has JSON inside. You have to parse this JSON to an NSDictionary then you can use its methods to retrieve response data. Try my JSON parser: http://github.com/H2CO3/CarbonateJSON

Example using my CarbonateJSON library:

```
NSDictionary *parsedResponse = [loginResponseString parseJson];
NSString *modhash = [[[parsedResponse objectForKey:@"json"] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"modhash"];
```

Comment: Alright, I'll look in to it. I wasn't trying to read the data from the loginResponseString though, that was just to log what was inside. I was trying to read from loginResponseData.

Comment: But loginResponseData is also just some sequence of bytes -- it has no knowledge if it's JSON or garbage, you can't do it as you want anyway.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. [__NSCFString parseJson]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde78260 is the error that I get.

Comment: You haven't yet added my library to your project, have you?

Comment: I copied your files into my project, is there a different way I should have done it?

Comment: Make sure they're compiled along with your app... (if you really can't get it to work, there are some more opensource JSON parsers for iOS).